# Slot-less stator in a DC motor

Tags: motor, ac, dc, brushless-dc-motor

How is it that slotless stators yield torque, on par with slotted stators, with less amount of copper windings, and no teeth to concentrate the flux towards the permanent magnets, and be efficient too. I understand the air gap losses are minimised by the use of rare earth magnets(NdFeB), and increase in rotor diameter maybe compensates for the less number of turns per coil. But even so, how could the absence of teeth be compensated with.

The stator still has laminated backing for the windings. How important is their role. Sorry if i am deviating.

[image: difference between slotted and slotless motor]
source: http://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/moco/features/22932

Comment: Can you link to an internet technical article where your claim comes from? If it's just some marketing or sales article be prepared for crit!

Comment: "on par" from what perspective? You probably can produce the same torque but the efficiency will be poor

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it only contains an unbacked claim, with a figure that does not come with a source. Defending a false or context-free claim makes no sense.

Comment: Hey i am no marketing guy, I am researching slotless motors, for application in powertools. They are energy efficient and can operate at high speeds. Now i am no electrical engineer, I am the Mech tasked to find a solution to the high speed, fast acceleration, and compact size motor.  That is when a slotless motor grabbed my attention. Check out the link below. http://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/moco/features/22932

Comment: I am sorry i am new to this platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, slotless motors are able to provide higher power/size ratios than slotted motors. The reasons for this are:

1. They have lower armature reaction. The massive airgap means that the field generated by the winding current does not act to saturate the backing iron, or demagnetize the pole flux. This means you can run extremely high currents in the coils and get correspondingly high amounts of torque. The torque production is generally limited by thermal considerations, rather than core saturation.
2. Slotless motors can use diamond windings. These do no have any end turns. End turns do not produce torque, but contribute resistance to the windings, so removing the end turns can increase efficiency significantly.

In the design you have shown, the fixed backing iron will still contribute core losses as the rotor poles pass over it. An alternative design rotates the backing iron as well, leaving the windings suspended in the airgap. This design can achieve extremely high RPMs efficiently, and if the windings are rotated (with the magnets stationary) it can have a very low moment of inertia too. This is why you see these designs in high performance servo applications.

For power tools, however, I doubt you'll see that much benefit from slotless. They really excel at intermittent high torque production. In applications where you are after continuous power output, I do not think the benefits would be so clear, and you would really have to do a full design analysis to get a handle on where you are at. Also, permanent magnet material is very expensive.

Comment: This is really insightful. Especially the end turn point. Thankyou for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Slotless motors are wound in such a way that if you were to look at an individual winding, the winding would have diamond-shaped "holes" between the rotor and the outer slotless steel.  The direction of the current in the windings causes current flow on the edge of these holes to flow around their perimeter causing the magnetic field that attracts or repels the rotor magnets in the same manner as a slotted stator.  Because the winding is very flat, the gap between the rotor and the stator steel is small, so the motor geometry yields good torque, especially since a comparably sizes slotted motor is often difficult or impossible to build in these small geometries, and the rotor diameter would be small, so that the mechanical advantage would yield less torque for the same magnetic force.  For example, a slotted permanent magnet motor with internal rotor with a diameter of an inch would be very hard to wind. As you increase diameter, the slotted stator torque has the advantage.

Comment: If so, then can slotless stators be used with squirrel cage induction rotors?

Comment: Yes, a squirrel cage may be used. It just won't be a synchronous motor.